# Check the integrity of files downloaded by repo sync

Tags: android, git, github, terminal, repo

I was downloading the source code of a Custom ROM of Android from GitHub, using `repo sync` command. During the download I had a bunch of errors, all related to `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`.

After running `repo sync` a couple of times more, I finally managed to download all the files. However, I would like to check the integrity of the files downloaded. That means, if I manually edit any of the files, or if any file is broken during download, I would like them to be downloaded and replaced.

I have scoured the net for such a command, but I can't find any for `repo`. I found `repo status` shows all the edits I have made, but I can't find any that'll actually check the integrity of the unchanged files.

I am using Ubuntu 18.10, by the way. Is there any such command?

Comment: I would say that as `repo` is a wrapper around git, I would say to run `git fsck` in all the git repositories created...

Comment: So, something like `repo forall -vc "git fsck --all"`?

Comment: I don't know repo but it seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repo forall -vc "git fsck --all"` did the trick.

`git fsck` checks for the integrity on each git repository, and running that inside `repo forall` executes it on all repositories created.

Thanks to Philippe for the idea in comment.

Comment: I know it's old but, does `--all` switch really exist for `git fsck`? Could not find it on current version, also checked history for `fsck.c` for git repo. That's strange.